# WPF - MVVM and switching VIEWs into one mainview

Tags: c#, mvvm, view, datacontext, mahapps.metro

i am new to C# and WPF, so sorry for my question :)

I have one mainview, and many views (user control element). I want show in mainview after click on menu (mahapps hamburgermenu) selected view from /Views/homepage.xaml or /Views/credits.xaml etc.

i have working code with GalaSoft.MvvmLight and mahapps haburger menu BUT :

every click on menu show current view (its still ok) but create new instance instead re-show created view. Because i have in sub-views textboxes, checkboxes etc with user filled values, everytime i click on menu, view are loaded complete new and all values are cleared.

i dont know, if is my problem clear :-D
Simply : i need one mainview that open inside other views, but not creating new intances,but show always view with user data content if is filled before

here is code : https://github.com/sgamescz/HH6C

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

The usual way to implement this is with a ContentControl and a DataTemplate. Typically your main view model will look something like this:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private object _CurrentPage;
    public object CurrentPage
    {
        get { return this._CurrentPage; }
        set
        {
            if (this._CurrentPage != value)
            {
                this._CurrentPage = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.CurrentPage); // <--- important that you do this
            }
        }
    }
```

You'll then create a view model class (e.g. MyPageViewModel) for each page type you want to display. In your MainWindow XAML you add a ContentControl like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />
```

Then you use a DataTemplate to tell WPF how to populate the content control whenever its Content is bound to an instance of your view model class:

```
<!-- can put put in your Window.Resources block or App.xaml resources block -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyPageViewModel">
    <Grid>  <!-- could also use a custom control if you like -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

When you create an instance of MyPageViewModel and assign it to CurrentPage you'll see the CustomControl populate with the DataTemplate.